# Trying to identify MOSFET - top markings DAX620 1411

Tags: mosfet, identification

My RC car ESC MOSFET is burnt. I'm trying to find a replacement for it, but I can't find the number or specs anywhere. The MOSFET has these numbers: DAX620 and below is 1411. Can someone help me identify it?
And the MOSFETs are burnt so bad I can't see what is written inside the little circle on top. On the others it reads p1r or j13, j14, j15,j16. Does this matter? 
I want to be an electronics engeneer, if you could explain, so i can learn new ways of finding component, it would be nice.

[image: PCB photo showing other similar devices]

Comment: upload a picture of it

Comment: also it might be this one (but its missing the 1411, so possibly not) https://vishay.com/docs/74475/sib911dk.pdf

Comment: 1411 could be some irrelevant manufacturing code like maybe it is manufactured in year 2014 week 11. Maybe it is a clone of IRF620, does it match?

Comment: A power MOS fet, a regulator or proprietary IC would be my guess.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-CJ36zHE3A